# I do not understand this bra-ket notation equality for BCFW recursion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, scattering

**Background:**

When learning about BCFW recursion I am shown the deformation equation:

$$\hat{p_1}=p_1 -zq \hspace{5mm}; \hspace{5mm} \hat{p_n} = p_n +zq$$

This deformation represents a $\langle1n]$ shift and $q$ is defined as $q=\lambda^\dot{\alpha}_1 \lambda^\alpha _n $

*To check under which circumstances* $\lim _{z \to \infty} \hat{A_n}(z)=0$, we consider deforming the 4-point MHV amplitude $A_4(1^- 2^- 3^+ 4^+)$.

Supposing we do a $\langle 1^- 2^-] $ shift then:

$$\hat{A_4}^{--}= \frac{\langle \hat{1}\hat{2}^3 \rangle}{\langle \hat{2}3 \rangle \langle 34\rangle \langle 4\hat{1} \rangle}$$

**Problem:**

In the notes, I am told to note that:

$$\langle \hat{1} \hat{2}\rangle= \left( \langle1|-z\langle 2|\right)|2\rangle =\langle 12\rangle  $$

where $\langle 22\rangle=0 $ has been used.

**How is this last equation true? I don't understand the middle term, how it was worked out or how it makes $\langle \hat{1} \hat{2} \rangle = \langle 12 \rangle$ I am pretty sure the first two equations are used in it but I don't see how.**

Comment: The last equality follows from $\langle 22\rangle=0$.

Comment: I understand that that equality has been used butI don't understand still where does the equation in the middle of the bra-ket come from? (The $-z\langle 2|) $ part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing a complex shift in order to enact the BCFW transformation, we take, as you pointed out,

$$ \hat{p}_1 = p_1 - zq~,~~~~~ \hat{p}_2 = p_2 + zq$$

Choosing to do a $\langle 12]$ shift means we make a clever choice for $q$ and work with spinors, which gives $$\hat{p}_1 = |1\rangle|1] - z|2\rangle|1] = (|1\rangle - z|2\rangle)|1] = |\hat{1}\rangle|1].$$
The choice of $q$ is determined from $\hat{p}_1^2 = 0 = \hat{p}_2^2$.

This can be seen by considering $\hat{p}_i^2 \propto 2p_i\cdot q = \langle iq\rangle[iq]$: we have to choose either $q \propto  |1\rangle[2|$ or $q \propto |2\rangle[1|$.

From the above, we have then that $|\hat{1}\rangle = |1\rangle - z|2\rangle$, which is the origin of the middle line. We should also note that $|\hat{2}\rangle = |2\rangle$, which you can check by shifting $p_2$ by the same $q$ as above.

Comment: The expansion makes perfect sense to me, but **I don't understand how** q was chosen based on the momentum conservation rules, because if that was the case wouldn't it be that:

$$\sum p_i = \sum \hat{p}_i = p_1 + p_2 = \hat{p}_1 + \hat{p}_2  $$

but then because the value of $zq$ changes sign in the equations:

$$\hat{p_1}=p_1 -zq \hspace{5mm}; \hspace{5mm} \hat{p_n} = p_n +zq$$

**don't they cancel out?**

And I don't understand how $(\hat{p}_i^2 = 0)$ helps either. 

I know this is based on $p_1 = |1\rangle|1]$ but could you help me understand the value of q?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Momentum conservation just tells you how to shift the other particle (so that they cancel in momentum conservation, as you correctly pointed out) and $\hat{p}_i^2 = 0$ just tells you what $q$ has to be.